# Pre-fetching logic in Rx

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm trying implement my own pre-fetching logic in rx.js. Here is example marble diagrams:

[image: Example marble diagrams]

I've modeled the problem as follows: There is a stream of *hints* that lets my program know that a user might want to *click* a certain link. I want to immediately send a request, but only *render* the *result* if the user indeed clicks the link.

Based on this, there are (at least) 3 things that can happen by the time the user clicks the link:

1. The correct result already returned form the server.
2. The request is still in progress
3. (Special) There is no request -- finished or in progress -- because the user somehow didn't trigger a hint first.

Some extra requirements:

- Only the latest hint should have a request in progress (i.e. cancel previous requests).
- Once the user clicks on a link, new hints should not trigger a request until the result is rendered
- New clicks should trigger new requests and cancel the previous request

I've actually found a solution, but it is convoluted, maybe incorrect, and mostly I'd just like to know if there is a better way of doing it (see below).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Now implemented in [hy-push-state](https://qwtel.com/hy-push-state/).